# Deploying EC2 instances within AZs in the same region using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I need to deploy 3 EC2 instances within 3 availability zones inside the same region using Terraform. I was trying to use the following structure:

```
variable "AVZ" {
  type = "map"
  default = {
  eu-central-1 = ["eu-central-1a","eu-central-1b","eu-central-1c"]
  eu-west-1    = ["eu-west-1a","eu-west-1b","eu-west-1c"]
 }
}
```

and

```
resource "aws_instance" "web-server0" {
   count = "${var.AWS_COUNT_WEB}"
   availability_zone = "${element(split(",", var.AVZ), count.index)}"
   ami = "${lookup(var.AWS_AMI,var.AWS_REGION)}"
   key_name = "${var.AWS_KEY_NAME}"
   instance_type = "${var.AWS_INSTANCE_TYPE}"
   associate_public_ip_address = "true"
   vpc_security_group_ids = [
     "${aws_security_group.allow_ssh.id}",
     "${aws_security_group.allow_web.id}"
   ]
 tags {
   Name = "web-server-b${count.index}"
   Tier = "blue"
   Role = "Web_Server"
      }
```

However it did not help much. It simply does not work I'm getting the following error:

```
At column 11, line 1: split: argument 2 should be type string, got type 
map in:
```

Does anybody knows how I can use variable type map, instead of string so I can map AZ to the Regions and lookup available AZs depending on Region defined and deploy EC2 instances depending on that results?

Thank you,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define AVZ as a map, but you do not use a key to access it.
A `split(",", ...)` is normally used in old code with string values instead of lists.

So try this interpolation:

```
availability_zone = "${element(var.AVZ[var.AWS_REGION], count.index)}"
```